# Passing the method to method

Tags: java

I have a method which uses Deque. In 1 place, sometimes I want to `Deque.pullFirst()` and sometimes `Deque.pullLast()`. It should depend on one of the arguments passed to the method. How do this with Java 8?

This is my try with Callable I know that it doesn't work but now you can understand what I want to achieve:

```
public class AppMain {
    public void iterateThroughQueue(Callable callable) { // error
         Deque<Integer> deq = new ArrayDeque<>();

         deq.add(1);
         deq.add(2);
         deq.add(3);

         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println(callable.apply(deq)); // error!
         }
         System.out.println("size after iteration = "  + deq.size());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
         AppMain.iterateThroughQueue(Deque::pollFirst); // error!
   }
}
```

Comment: `Callable` doesn't have an `apply()` method.

Comment: I know but now ya understand what I want to do.

Comment: Use `java.util.function.Function` instead of `Callable`.

Comment: Function has no side effects and I need side effects in polling from Deque here. And how to pass `Deque::polFirst` which is not static as Function?

Comment: @Whffgfv Obggcg. What do you mean by "side effect"?

Comment: side effect of `poll` is removing the element from Deque.

Comment: @Whffgfv Obggcg. Nothing is preventing from `Function.apply` to have side effect.

Comment: OK, thx so Java functions are extraoridinary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method references are either:

- `Consumer<T>`, which means they take a parameter and return nothing. For example `System.out::println` is a `Consumer<String>`.
- `Producer<T>`, which means they take no parameter and return something. For example `UUID::randomUUID` is a `Producer<UUID>`.
- `Function<T,Z>`, which means they take a parameter of type T (can be the instance on which to apply the method) and return a result of type Z, in your case `Deque::pollFirst` take is a `Function<Deque<Integer>, Integer>`. Another example is `deq::add` where deq is an instance of `Deque<Integer>` which would be a `Function<Integer, Boolean>` .

So you should be using `Function<Deque<Integer>, Integer>` instead of Callable which is for something completely different. Also `iterateThroughQueue(...)` need to be `static`.

Answer (score 2):

`Callable` will not work here,  but `Function` will.

You could try instead this:

```
public static void iterateThroughQueue(Function<Deque<Integer>, Integer> function) {

    Deque<Integer> deq = new ArrayDeque<>();

    deq.add(1);
    deq.add(2);
    deq.add(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println(function.apply(deq));
    }
    System.out.println("size after iteration = "  + deq.size());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    iterateThroughQueue(Deque::pollFirst);
}
```

This prints:

```
1
2
3
size after iteration = 0
```